# Protect wp-login.php without plugin or hide URL

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

Password protection is in place for wp-admin, but wp-login.php can bypass this. I'd like to password protect wp-login.php this as well.

I saw a while ago that:
<filesmatch "wp-login.php">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "WordPress Admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/USERNAME/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd"
require valid-user

OR

"ErrorDocument 401 “Unauthorized Access”
ErrorDocument 403 “Forbidden”
<FilesMatch “wp-login.php”>
AuthName “Authorized Only”
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/.wpadmin
Require valid-user

OR

just changing FilesMatch to Files could work.

However, I've tried all of the above and it just triggers an internal server error due to misconfiguration/500.

Not looking to hide the wp-login page as I've read many articles arguing whether this is effective or not, while  one of the most famous plugins for hiding the URL - has a small number (even in ratio to high successes) of having their site crash or database exposed. I would therefore like to avoid.

Have a security plugin, but worried it might conflict with another plugin, or cause to many resources to be pulled.

Anyone have any idea how to protect wp-login.php?

Can't use IP address blocking - unless potentially blocking all IPs including ours and just using wp-admin to login. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: _"and it just triggers an internal server error due to misconfiguration/500."_ - then you should go and check what the error log has to say about that.

Comment: ErrorDocument takes two arguments, Change responses for HTTP errors - which is due to ", but without " it's not accepted. I saw in a lot of forums that the above codes stopped working around 2020, and that people were looking into it, but didn't come back to any of those forums. As its been a few years since, I wondered if anyone had found a work round or if I would be okay to block wp-login.php from all IPs, and if so could you still enter via wp-admin? I know it's probably a silly question, but still learning.

Comment: That's the wrong kind of quotes in the ErrorDocument directive there, you used `“`, but it needs to be simple `"`.

Comment: What a numpty, I had copied the code into note and then on here, so I didn't think it could be that. But I didn't look at where I got the code from, and sure enough there was a  “ instead of ". Thanks, really need to get into the habit of checking this more. Seems to be working now. Do you perhaps know how safe it is to block wp-login.php this way? Just got some last minute worries. Its a not-for-profit, and really want to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

### Missing a line in HTACCESS file

You are correct in your proceeding, but you are missing a line of code that should go in the first line of the `.htaccess` file from the root directory of your wordpress installation:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

With this you will avoid the error.

I strongly advice any wordpress administrator to apply this procedure to protect your site's admin.

You can find the entire explanation and instructions on [this website](https://cybmeta.com/htaccess-proteger-con-contrasena-wplogin-y-wp-admin) that's in Spanish.